# Having a hard time using the GCP translate API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, translate

I'm building a very simple program in Python. All I want is to be able to input a text and get the translated text in another language.

The program will be used on different computers, the API key can be stored in the code as I will be the only one using it.

I can't figure out how to do it, I've searched for hours without any progress. What is the simplest way of getting it to work?

EDIT: so far I have this:

```
from google.cloud import translate

key = "...."
translate_client = translate.Client()
service = translate.build(developerKey=key)
service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey=key)
translation = service.translate(['Detta är ett test'], target_language = 'en')
    print(translation)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code may help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from google.cloud import translate
from apiclient.discovery import build
key = 'YOUR API KEY'
translate_client = translate.Client()
service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey=key)
translation = service.translations().list(source='es',target='en',q=['Esto es un 
texto traducido']).execute()
print(translation)
```

Consult this [link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/python/latest/index.html) for the Translation API methods Python reference document.

Comment: Thanks, I get this error though: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient.discovery'"

I've tried "pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client" but to no avail.

Comment: Did you executed it with `sudo`? For instance `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: I didn't, I get an error when executing with sudo. "'sudo' is not recognized as an interna or external comman,.."

Comment: Are you using a windows machine? If this is your case then try running `python -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: Yes I am using a windows machine. {python} gives "NameError: name 'python' is not defined. {py} gives me "Python 3.6.4 (v3......)

Comment: This is due to the environment variables are not set, you could follow [this Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) as a reference for setting the environment variables. Keep in mind that the paths may vary depending on your python version and its installation

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully did it by using another approach. I've created a service account in `Google Cloud Platform` and saved the credentials to a `json` file. Then, I've set a global environment for my credentials:

```
import os
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

# We setup the global variable for GCP service account credentials

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'[path to your file].json'

# We specify the path to the file we want to load

filepath = r''

# Instantiate the Google Translation API Client

translate_client = translate.Client()

output = []

for chunk in chunker(elements, 100): #elements are the rows from an Excel 
    temp = translate_client.translate(
        chunk,
        target_language='fr'
    )
    output.extend(temp)
```